# Is is possible to open and arrange multiple new windows from the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

Working on Mac OSX 11.2.1.

I can successfully open some tools from my Terminal (e.g. VS Code using `code` CLI or my browser using `webbrowser` in my Python script), but the opening window sizes and positions are sometimes not as I would like.

Is is possible, from the Terminal, to select *n* windows (applications) to put side by side? Not sure if there's an "API" to arrange windows positions on my laptop...

Thanks!

Comment: For general questions about using Apple software, see [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

tmux is what you need. You can assign window split number and size, initialize multiple window with different program running by writing bash scripts, and detach/reattach session easily.